# I need to hide directory from url using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to remove directories from my local website url:

**Current url** : `http://localhost/example/trunk/frontend/www` 
**Needed url** : `http://localhost/example/frontend`

I need to remove ***trunk*** and ***www*** folders from url without changing files (css, js, images, ...etc) paths.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/trunk/[^/]*/www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(example)/([^/]+)(/.*|)$ /$1/trunk/$2/www$3 [L,NC]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/

RewriteRule ^((?!trunk)[^/]+)(/.*|)$ trunk/$2/www$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry. i have put .htaccess file in example folder (root), and when i'm trying to access from browser displays folders view for my project. mod_rewrite already enabled and i have enabled allowoverride from apache config. then what is the problem? thank you for help :)

Comment: current url is: http://localhost/example/trunk/frontend/www
needed url is: http://localhost/example/frontend
and i'm entring http://localhost/example/frontend
i put the .htaccess in example folder because the structure of folders is: webroot/example/trunk/frontend/www